# Web.Config Transform not changing any values

Tags: xml, web-config-transform

I'm trying to set up a web.config transform to modify some values.  I am using this example given by Octopus Deploy:

http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Configuration+files

ultra-slimmed down version of web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

the transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I'm using this tool to preview the transformation:
https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/

as you can see it doesn't do anything.  I've looked at a lot of examples, but obviously I'm missing something.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(I've also tried this with no luck):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web>
      <compilation debug="false" xdt:Transform="Replace">
      </compilation >
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you sure about the namespace of the input xml? If you change it from `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"` to `xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"` the `debug` attribute is removed from the output.

Comment: thank you Matthias, that was it... I looked at about 10 different resources, and none of them mentioned that I had to do that.  I'll mark that as the answer if you'd like to submit it as such.

Comment: What's really frustrating is that I used Visual Studio to automatically generate the transform files.  You'd think it would be smart enough to add that part in to the original web.config if it was required for the transform.

Comment: No change to the original web.config is required

Comment: Yes, it seems in the example this 
  `<xdt:Import assembly="AppHarbor.TransformTester" namespace="AppHarbor.TransformTester.Transforms"/>` was missing in the transform because then it's working without any namespace in  the `configuration` of the web.config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transform works as intended on the mentioned online preview tool for web.config transformations https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/ when you change the namespace of the web.config file from

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

to

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

When this transform

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

is applied to the adjusted web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

the `debug` attribute is removed from the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0">
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Update:** As mentioned in the comments, the configuration of the web.config file shouldn't have any namespace at all. Instead, it's necessary to add this import

```
<xdt:Import assembly="AppHarbor.TransformTester" 
            namespace="AppHarbor.TransformTester.Transforms"/>
```

to the transform file (at least, when testing with the mentioned online transformation tester):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
<xdt:Import assembly="AppHarbor.TransformTester" 
     namespace="AppHarbor.TransformTester.Transforms"/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Actually, the entire namespace declaration should be removed from the `<configuration>` element in the web.config. `configuration` is not in a namespace.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks for the info, just found this info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee248644%28v=vs.100%29.aspx (not knowing if it applies to the settings used here). Answer was given based on the example mentioned here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx

Comment: You read the examples wrong. All the examples on that page are of _transformation files_, not of web.config files.

Comment: @JohnSaunders So the transform would work without the namespace in actual deployment and is only needed by the online web.config transform tester mentioned in OP? Just tested there without namespace in the web.config and it doesn't work there as intended.

Comment: Their example has no namespace in the web.config. See https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thank you for the info and the example, I think I just found the real answer as prev answer was more about a guess. Will update in a minute.